# Como eu faço para adicionar um pane dentro de um outro pane através de código como javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

Eu já sei como fazer isso quando se trata de um `AnchorPane`, é algo mais ou menos assim:

```
AnchorPane ap = new AnchoPane();
Label lbl = new Label("Qualquer");
ap.getChildren().add(lbl);
```

Mas quando de trata de um `Pane` normal, eu só consigo chamar o `getChildrenUnmodifiable()`, e se depois eu chamo o `add(lbl)` é lançada a seguinte exceção:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Forneça um código que seja reproduzível. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

O Pane também possui o método `getChildren()`. Você pode usá-lo da mesma forma que o AnchorPane. Verifique se você está utilizando o import correto: `import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;`

Veja a documentação da classe nesse link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html

Para facilitar tirei um print da parte que interessa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho de código para teste:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane pane = new Pane();

            Pane otherPane = new Pane();
            pane.getChildren().add(otherPane);

            Label label = new Label("Qualquer");
            otherPane.getChildren().add(label);


            Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```